# How to automatically remove remote-tracking branch when the corresponding local branch is removed using git

Tags: git, branch, remote-branch

The current setup:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  feature
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/feature
```

After `feature` branch is merged, I would like to remove local branch `feature` and remote-tracking branch `origin/feature`. The remote branch on server is already removed in this case.

The commands I need is:

```
$ git branch -d features
$ git branch -d -r origin/features
```

Is there a way that the second command is automatically triggered when the corresponding local branch is removed? Any `git-config` settings?

Answer (score 0):

If you set `git config fetch.prune true`, then the second command can be a simple `git fetch`.

That will prune any remote tracking branch `origin/feature`, since `feature` was already deleted on the server side.

Even if you don't use the config setting, a `git fetch --prune` would do the same.

In both cases, the advantage is that it will prune any remote tracking branch already deleted on the server (instead of just one branch).